# promises exercise in JS

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm training on JS promises with a short URL generator exercise and I'm stuck. The console sends me back: Resultat: undefined.
I need help please !

```js
import express from 'express';
import shortUrl from 'node-url-shortener';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('postUrl');
})

router.post('/test', (req, res) => {

  const getShortUrl = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const test = shortUrl.short('https://google.com', (err, url) => {
          return url;
      });
      resolve(test)
    })
  }

  getShortUrl()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Resultat : ' + result)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error : ' + err)
    })

  res.render('getShortUrl');
})

export { router }
```

Comment: You need to resolve the promise in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `result(test)` to inside the callback. Like this:

```js
import express from 'express';
import shortUrl from 'node-url-shortener';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('postUrl');
})

router.post('/test', (req, res) => {

  const getShortUrl = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      shortUrl.short('https://google.com', (err, url) => {
          resolve(url);
      });
      
    })
  }

  getShortUrl()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Resultat : ' + result)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error : ' + err)
    })

  res.render('getShortUrl');
})

export { router }
```

Comment: Thank you Nelson ;)